# Calculate histogram from raster stored in GeoServer

Tags: raster, geoserver, openlayers, histogram

I have a raster stored in GeoServer which I can show it with Openlayers in my web page:

```
raster = new TileLayer({
  source: new TileWMS({
    url: 'http://myip/geoserver/myworkspace/wms',
    params: {'LAYERS': 'myworkspace:mylayer','TILED': true},
    serverType: 'geoserver',
  });
});
```

[image: graphic]

But I want to show also an histogram. I found a way to get the value of a pixel given a coordinate with the following url:

```
urlRequest = this.raster.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
    myCoordinate,myview.getResolution(),
    'EPSG:3857',{'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'});
```

Is there a similar request for getting all values from the raster given an extent instead of a single coordinate or is there a better way to calculate an histogram?

Comment: note that a tile is just a simple image. So, you would basically make a historgram of color values and not the real raster values. I am not sure if OpenLayers is the right tool for obtaining statistics of your raster image. Even though you can query the values per coordinate. This seems more like a hack to me ...

Comment: It is not necessary to be done with OpenLayers. I just need to find a way to retrieve all values from a raster with any request like: myip:8080/geoserver/myworkspace/wcs?&request=GetValues&layers=mylayer&bbox=myextent then I would calculate the histogram with javascript. I dont know if I have to use wcs or wms or maybe wps

Comment: Probably wps is the best way but you could grab the image data using WCS and process that.